# ASP.NET MVC API Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing a website that will be loaded for genuine users(without registeration or login requirement) using API for front-end data. I want data to be secured.

I read about authentications and thus created secret key at server end but stuck at a point as to how can I create secret key for clients and verify the user is genuine and no attack to website is done.

Comment: I think it should help: https://auth0.com/blog/auth0-passwordless-email-authentication-and-sms-login-without-passwords/

Comment: Hello,For login purpose there is registeration and login form given on the website... I want to secure front-end data from attacks.

Comment: I think you are searching for this: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Token-Based-Authentication-6db2acc9

Comment: Yes... And i created server side key and confused as how to generate client side token without any input from user.

Comment: Please! upload the code which you have tried so far. 

**Note**: You need to create an API for users where the user can log in using API and then generate the token. After that using that token they can access API from the front end.

Comment: I've not coded for this api...Let me explain what is actually required as I may have failed earlier. I've a Website that contains directories and when user enters website url then api will get the data that will be loaded only for genuine users and not for the attackers. There is no demand of login or registeration form for loading home page data. I went through blogs but couldn't find any blog that demonstrates authentication without user details such as username or password or email.